# Как установить тему для Activity?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. У меня в андройд приложении есть два активити на первой тема работает, а на второй нет, хотя я в обеих устанавливаю её вот так

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
}
```

вот как это примерно выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как исправить чтобы поменялся цвет statusbar. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Задать общую тему можно таким образом в манифесте:

```
<application
        ....
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ....
</application>
```

Код темы:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Здесь именно `colorPrimaryDark` отвечает за цвет статусбара.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прописал не работает

Comment: setTheme(R.style.AppDefault); из кода удалили?

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте у этой активти нужно установить android:theme="@style/Name
Как то так:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
                  android:theme="@style/Name"/>
```

Далее в папке values в файле styles:

```
 <!-- Стандартная тема для всего приложения. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
 <!-- Тема для вашего активити -->
    <style name="Name" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#36a438</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#cf8c34</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#fe2ee6</item>
 </style>
```

Если хотите, что бы тема была у всего активити, то параметр theme надо устанавливать ко всему application:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

Мало того, обратите внимание на то, как и откуда вы вызываете ваше активити. Например, если вы вызываете активити как

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TargetActivity.class));
```

А потом пользуетесь inflate, то надутая view получит контекст всего аппликейшена, а значит и его тему. (https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/?utm_campaign=adp_series_prepareformultiwindow_032316&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog)

Если все вышеназванное не помогает - привидите более подробную информацию как и что вы делаете.